# JQuery sortable elements not sortable and positioned to pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

My problem is that I can not sort elements in my unordered list. 
The placeholder is always shown in the first row, where the first element is. (when I drag element). Oder elements are not moving at all and are not giving space to element currently dragging (which should be default functionality of sortable).

[Here my code pen example](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/ZOaRag?editors=1010)

(to add elements to the list just click 'Add' several times. To enable sortable functionality, click button 'Sort'. To disable sortable functionality click 'Not sortable')

For sortable I have properties below:

```
$("#btnSortable").click(function() {
  $("#ulNotes").sortable({
    handle: '.divText',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    placeholder: 'sortablePlaceholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    forceHelperSize: true,
    cursorAt: {left: 0, top: 0}        
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `class="list-unstyled"` and hold an element above another element it works !! I think that the problem is your css.

Comment: Thanks. I see that another problem is sorting elements when they are in different columns...

Comment: You can also post this as answer. It's great, you solved my biggest problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
     #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
     #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; float:left; border:1px solid black;width:30%;}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```